# JQL: Filter other query

Tags: jira, jql

I have a saved query from another user, showing all open tickets of our developers.

What I want to do is to filter this query for tickets to me:

```
ticket in (other query) and assignee = currentUser()
```

Is something like this possible in JQL?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `AND` together with the other JQL query, for example, if the original query is:

```
project =  Development and status = open
```

and now you wish to select the issues that belongs to you:

```
project =  Development and status = open and assignee = currentUser()
```

If the other query is saved you could use the filter name:

```
filter = "Dev open issues" and assignee = currentUser()
```

Or by Filter ID:

```
filter = "10302" and assignee = currentUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the following JQL:

```
filter = "Your saved filter name here" AND assignee = currentUser()
```